# POI 3.12 VLOOKUP error: Specified named range 'other sheet name' does not exist in the current workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can apache POI 3.12 do a VLOOKUP to a different sheet? Say I have a formula as follows (this formula works in Excel):

```
VLOOKUP(N6,Baskets,14,0)
```

I'm trying to use it to get a value from the Baskets sheet a use it on another sheet.

It is giving this error:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'Baskets' does not exist in the current workbook.
```

In searching the web on this I haven't really found an answer. [The POI API    for VLOOKUP](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/Vlookup.html) kind of suggests to me that it can only be used for use in ranges specified on the current sheet. However, I'm probably just adding meaning to the argument name of table_array. That is all that I've found for documentation on it.

**After the answer was found here is the source of my confusion**
According to the [Libre Office documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) the array argument has to have more than one column. The first column must contain the search criterion and the other columns must contain the column used as the index argument. Finally, the index argument is relative to the array argument not the workbook's column indexes.

Comment: Did you try a valid other-sheet reference, e.g. `Baskets!A1:D4`, depending on the cell range you want to do a lookup?

Comment: Yes, I tried every variation I could think of. There is a lot of different syntax you can try and maybe I didn't try them all. If you've done this please show me the syntax that worked and I'll try it.

Comment: What happens when you upgrade to the latest version of Apache POI, currently 3.14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a working example for you.

```
formulaCell.setCellFormula("IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP('" + Baskets + "'!$A$4:$A$360,'" + processName + "'!$A$2:$B$80,2,FALSE)),\"\",VLOOKUP('" + Baskets + "'!$A$4:$A$360,'" + processName + "'!$A$2:$B$80,2,FALSE))" );
```

I use a VLOOKUP to find out, wheter the data at the different sheet equals my data at the current sheet.

The `processName` is only a String to compare my data.

My problem was the specified range at the other sheet `!$A$4:$A$360` the `""` and `''` around the VLOOKUP statement.

Comment: great, I will try to apply this example.